# Why CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL is not working on the link?

Tags: php, redirect, curl

`CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` is refusing to work on [this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/01/28/colors-in-corporate-branding-and-design/) URL.

The result is exactly the same as the original URL, but if you follow the URL in your browser, it clearly redirects.

What is going on here?

Here is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_exec($ch);

$redirectURL = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
echo $redirectURL;

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: When I run your code, it echoes the final URL, exactly the same as the browser. You'll need to add more details, such as PHP version, curl version, and operating system.

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley Yeah, worked for me too when run on its own. I'm trying it through an ajax call but no luck.

Comment: any luck? i am in same problem too!!!